# SFTP with private Key, no user name

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have a client configuration that asks for accessing their SFTP server with the supplied SFTP key, no user name. To test the system locally, we are using our own SFTP server. But, even with private key, our SFTP server prompts for user name; which I remember is the right thing to do. SSH does ask for user name with private key; no password is required.

So question: How can I go around setting that SFTP server to just "figure" out the user from the private key? Or just plain allow me to login with JUST the private key.

Thanks,
-Amit

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go around setting that SFTP server to just "figure" out the user from the private key? Or just plain allow me to login with JUST the private key.

No. The private key does not contain any information about target users.

Comment: Hence the question. The client setup works; I am wondering how.